# trying to run command 'flutter pub run build_runner build' with build runner 2.0.3 with web3dart 2.4.1

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, decentralized-applications, web3dart

trying to generate .g.dart file from abi json then getting these error

`

```
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 139ms

[INFO] Precompiling build script......
[WARNING] .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart:9:8: Error: Error when reading '../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/web3dart-2.4.1/lib/src/builder/builders.dart': No such file or directory
import 'package:web3dart/src/builder/builders.dart' as _i2;
       ^
.dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart:18:10: Error: Undefined name 'abiGenerator'.
    [_i2.abiGenerator],
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
.dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart:32:9: Error: Undefined name 'deleteSource'.
    _i2.deleteSource,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
[INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 400ms

[SEVERE] Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart.
This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition.
```

`

i tried to downgrade build_runner but still getting error